# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerexception:incorrect syntax near'='

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm getting the error in the first line i guess! Please help me out in dealing with it. I'm basically trying to execute a query through my front end

```
try {            
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select *from Login Username ='"+username+"' and Password  '"+password+"'");
        rs.last();
        int counter = rs.getRow();
        if (counter==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username and Password Correct","Username and Password Correct",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            this.setVisible(false);
            new Menu().setVisible(true);
            hide();
            }else{
            jt_username.setText("");
            jp_password.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error","Username and Password Incorrect",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);            
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: I've replaced my code with where statement but now its showing this
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerexception:incorrect syntax near".

Comment: There are four things wrong that I can see. (1) You shouldn't store  passwords in plain text, hash them. (2) Missing `WHERE` between Login and Username (3) missing an `=` after Password. (4) **vulnerable to SQL injection**. Use parameterised queries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I've sorted out the error and now its working perfectly fine :)

Comment: If all you have done is fixed the syntax errors it is **not** working fine. It will break for passwords/user names containing single quotes. And this will also allow SQL injection allowing your login to be entirely bypassed (or worse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is missing the `WHERE` keyword. Try this on for size:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Login WHERE Username ='"+username+"' and Password=  '"+password+"'");
```

Comment: Please show how to perform parameterised queries in your answer. There is no value in just fixing the trivial syntax errors.